# Como utilizar o 'scan' para uma variável numérica [SAS]

Tags: macro, sas

Tenho uma tabela deste género:

Lista_ID  1 4 7 10

(No total são 100 números)

Quero chamá-los para uma macro que criei. Estava a tentar fazê-lo com o Scan, mas li que era apenas para variáveis de texto. Dava-me que as minhas variáveis não estavam inicializadas.

Aqui segue o código:

```
proc sql; 
select ID INTO: LISTA_ID SEPARATED BY '*' from 
WORK.AMOSTRA;
run;


PROC SQL;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO: NR SEPARATED BY '*' FROM
WORK.AMOSTRA;
RUN;

%MACRO CICLO_teste();

%LET LIM_MSISDN = %EVAL(NR);
%LET I = %EVAL(1);

%DO %WHILE (&I<= &LIM_MSISDN);
%LET REF = %SCAN(LISTA_ID,&I,,'*'); 

DATA WORK.UP&REF;
SET WORK.BASE&REF;
FORMAT PERC_ACUM 9.3;
IF FIRST.ID_CLIENTE THEN PERC_ACUM=0;
PERC_ACUM+PERC;
RUN; 



%LET I = %EVAL(&I+1);
%END;
%MEND;

%CICLO_TESTE;
```

A ideia é correr esta macro para cada um dos ID's contidos em LISTA_ID e referenciados em work.base&ref e work.up&ref. Como o posso fazer?

Answer (score 1):

Olá! Primeiramente, acredito que você esteja confundindo a função **scan** (que recebe apenas valores de texto) com a macro função **%scan**. Sempre que você tiver o símbolo "*%*" antes do nome da função, trata-se de uma macro função, que recebe como argumento uma macro variável. Dessa forma, a macro função **%scan** também pode ser usada com valores numéricos.

Acredito que o warning que apareceu foi algo do tipo *"WARNING: Macro variable LIM_MSISDN is not initialized"*. Isso aconteceu porque você esqueceu de colocar o ampersand (símbolo &") antes do texto NR, indicando que NR é uma macro variável, nesse trecho aqui: **%LET LIM_MSISDN = %EVAL(NR)** . Além disso, você não precisa usar **%eval** aqui, você só usa **%eval** quando vai fazer alguma operação aritmética com o valor da macro variável, o que não é o caso aqui; aqui você só quer copiar o valor. 
Coloquei abaixo duas sugestões de códigos que devem funcionar para o que você quer fazer:

**Código 1: não tenho certeza se funciona porque nunca usei '*' para separar elementos em macro variáveis e não tenho SAS aqui pra testar:**

```
proc sql; 
    select ID INTO: LISTA_ID SEPARATED BY '*' from 
    WORK.AMOSTRA;
quit;

%MACRO CICLO_teste;

    %let num_elementos = %sysfunc(countw(&LISTA_ID.), %str(*));

    %do i = 1 %to &num_elementos.;

        %let ref = %scan(&LISTA_ID., &i., *);

        DATA WORK.UP&REF;
            SET WORK.BASE&REF;
            FORMAT PERC_ACUM 9.3;
            IF FIRST.ID_CLIENTE THEN PERC_ACUM=0;
        PERC_ACUM+PERC;
    RUN; 
    %end;

%MEND CICLO_TESTE;
%CICLO_TESTE;
```

**Código 2: usando espaço para separar os elementos da macro variável:**

```
proc sql; 
    select ID INTO: LISTA_ID SEPARATED BY ' ' from 
    WORK.AMOSTRA;
quit;

%MACRO CICLO_teste;

    %let num_elementos = %sysfunc(countw(&LISTA_ID.));

    %do i = 1 %to &num_elementos.;

        %let ref = %scan(&LISTA_ID., &i.,' ');/*Como usei espaço como separador, nem precisava colocar o terceiro argumento, mas deixei aqui pra ficar explícito*/

        DATA WORK.UP&REF;
            SET WORK.BASE&REF;
            FORMAT PERC_ACUM 9.3;
            IF FIRST.ID_CLIENTE THEN PERC_ACUM=0;
        PERC_ACUM+PERC;
    RUN; 
    %end;

%MEND CICLO_TESTE;
%CICLO_TESTE;
```